# Getting mean of a subset within data.frame

Tags: r

I have a data frame that displays sales data, split by Year, and Quarter.
What I want to do is plot Demand with respect to Price, however I'd like to see price as difference from average annual price.

What I have thus far is

```
Year <- c(1,1,1,2,2,2,2)
Quarter <- c(1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4)
Price <- c(10,15,20,15,15,20,20,25)
Demand <- c(12,15,10,12,10,15,12,12)
sales_data <- data.frame(Year, Quarter, Price, Demand)
attach(sales_data)    
plot(Price-mean(Price),Demand)
#Correct prices:
#year1 -5,0,5,0
#year2 -5,0,0,5
```

Of course the issue with this is that mean() uses all of data not just data from each year separately.

Comment: Please show a reproducible example.

Comment: Using `ggplot2` and `dplyr` `sales_data %>% group_by(Year) %>% mutate(Price = Price - mean(Price)) %>% ggplot(., aes(x=Price, y = Demand)) + geom_point()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using base by function

```
plot(unlist(by(sales_data, sales_data$Year, function(x) x$Price - mean(x$Price))),Demand)
```